# Wordpress cron value in wp_options is too large

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running a Wordpress with WooCommerce, WPML, CalderaForms.

I disabled WP-CRON by adding in wp-config.php because of the following issue happening before and still:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

I run a CRON job every night at 1 AM to `wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

Then I check the running queries in MySQL with :

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

I can observe that with refreshing the query every second, there's something running from Wordpress on the `cron` entry in wp_options. Sometimes a query updating the entry, sometimes other queries.

I made a SELECT on that entry and the result is really, really large, to the point that the query takes time to load.

There are thousdands of lines with `delete_transient_version`. I can't even copy the content because the page gets slow and stops working.

Why is wordpress updating `cron`from in wp_options and why is it filled so much ?

The CRON stops after a few minutes but it runs a lot of queries and we're talking GB according to the PhpMyAdmin "status" page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue. Not sure why it created so much CRON events, but I remember doing multiple imports of bulk products into WooCommerce, and sometimes it broke and that must be the reason why cron jobs were so polluted. Every time WP-CRON runs, it tries to clean the database but it takes so much time that it treats a few ones at a time and there are thousands of events.

I simply did an UPDATE to empty the entry :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'cron'
```

After that, running `wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` or just visiting the site added less than 10 CRON events and now the website rungs 4 seconds faster, I'm so relieved I finally got it back working and fast !